# Remove elementary OS and install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

My laptop came with elementary OS, but it doesn't work well. Touchpad inoperational. Wifi intermittent. Difficult to download apps. The BIOS won't let me change boot order.

How can I remove elementary OS and install Ubuntu?

Comment: elementary OS is based off Ubuntu. Keep in mind that there is no guarantee Ubuntu will work any better.

Answer (score 1):

Download a Ubuntu live CD, extract it on a pen drive with unetbootin or any similar tool and start the installation process.

Don't forget to backup your data.

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot from live distro? If yes, download gparted, delete the entire partition (dont format it, let this to ubuntu), then reboot. The Ubuntu instalation wizard must start. Take a look at your BIOS if theres a place for you to change the secure boot mode(i think) to UEFI, mine is set to CMOS and UEFI for ex, my notebook sometimes doesnt let me change the boot device too and its because:

1) the USB ISO installation failed and I have to reburn it, even if the app said everything was right
2) I have to change my secure boot to CMOS and UEFI

But as someone said, eOS is based on ubuntu, maybe try Ubuntu 19.xx (eOS is based on 18.04).

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to boot off a partition manager utility, such as [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php), either the CD / USB version.
Then delete the existing partitions on the hard drive completely, reboot - and then boot off the Ubuntu installation media.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to "remove" Ubuntu. Just boot up from a live USB drive with Ubuntu on it and proceed the installation normally.

Just make sure that you install the Ubuntu system in the eOS partition and it's done.